# Jpackage - Accessing resources bundled with package

Tags: javafx, ioexception, jpackage

I'm packaging my JavaFX project as installer using [JPackageScriptFX](https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX), and I've created a folder called "resources" which is present at the basedir of my source package. I've included this folder in my package by passing `--app-content resources` flag:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/jpackage \
--type $INSTALLER_TYPE \
--dest target/installer \
--input target/libs \
--app-content resources \
--name "$NAME" \
--vendor "$VENDOR" \
--main-class ${MAIN_CLASS}.AppLauncher \
--main-jar ${MAIN_JAR} \
--java-options -Xmx2048m \
--runtime-image target/java-runtime \
--icon ${ICON} \
--app-version ${APP_VERSION} \
```

This is my source code folders directory structure:

```
Project
|
|-resources
|         |-icon.png
|
|-src
|
|-pom.xml
.
.
.
```

After the package is created and installed successfully, the installation directory's structure is:

```
Project
|
|-bin
|   |-project
|
|-lib
|   |-app
|   |   |-project.jar
|   |   |-project.cfg
|   |
|   |-resources
|   |         |-icon.png
|   |
|   |-runtime
|
|-share
```

When I'm running the project, I'm getting the `FileNotFoundException` on method:
`DBIO.loadResource`

```
public class DBIO {
    private DBIO(){/*NOTHING*/}
    private static InputStream loadResource(String path){
        try{
            return new FileInputStream("resources/"+path);
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static final Image LOGO = new Image(loadResource("icon.png"));
}
```

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources/icon.png (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at project.app.DBIO.loadResource(DBIO.java:24)
    at project.app.DBIO.<clinit>(DBIO.java:30)
    at project.app.EULAController.<clinit>(EULAController.java:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.ensureClassInitialized(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.newConstructorAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.acquireConstructorAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:941)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:983)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:230)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:757)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2853)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2649)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2563)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2531)
    at project.app.App.start(App.java:16)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$10(GtkApplication.java:263)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at project.app.EULAController.<clinit>(EULAController.java:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.ensureClassInitialized(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.newConstructorAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.acquireConstructorAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:941)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:983)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:230)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:757)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2853)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2649)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2563)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2531)
    at project.app.App.start(App.java:16)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$10(GtkApplication.java:263)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.File.toPath()" because "file" is null
    at project.app.DBIO.writeToFile(DBIO.java:73)
    at project.app.Util.log(Util.java:43)
    at project.app.DBIO.loadResource(DBIO.java:26)
    at project.app.DBIO.<clinit>(DBIO.java:30)
    ... 27 more
```

EDIT:
If I copy the resources folder inside `Project/bin` the project starts working. That means the program is looking for resources folder inside bin. How should I point it to look in the correct location (inside `/lib`)?

Comment: Is it an option to package the resources inside your jar file instead, like documented in these [standard resource lookup instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other) or the [Eden JavaFX resource tutorial](https://edencoding.com/where-to-put-resource-files-in-javafx/)?  Why do you want to use jpackage to package resources in this case?

Comment: I recommend you to package the resources inside the JAR and if this is not possible for any reason, then package them inside the JAR nevertheless, but extract them on application startup to "userhome/.appname". Then you will never run into this troubles.

Comment: I was initially packaging the file inside the jar, but my other method utilizing external library in other class is unable to get this file, it asks either for a file or a path which is not readable from getResourceAsStream().

Comment: Hard to answer then without knowing how the resources are accessed.

Comment: @jewelsea One of the external library, PDFBox has a method to insert image called `PDImageXObject.createFromFile` and `PDImageXObject.createFromFileByContent`. They use image path and java.io.File respectively to get the Image file. I've tried passing the packaged resource as stream to both, but they throw `Can't read input stream!` error.

Comment: Well I can find a workaround for the PDFBox issue. My main point is, if jpackage is capable of including additional folders, then it will be a good alternative to put our resource files in it instead of compulsorily bundling them with the JAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resources` folder can be included into a project through jpackage using

`--app-content resources`

This folder will be present as `Project/lib/resources` in Linux and `Project\resources` in Windows.

Access to this folder can be made through:

```
String resourcesDir = new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
.getLocation().getPath()).getParentFile().getParent()+"/resources/";
```

*Points to notice*

- Accessing an image (to load into `Image()`) would require you to prefix `file://` or `file:\\`.
- If there is a space in the path, you'd require `URLDecoder.decode(resourcesDir,"UTF-8")`.

Answer (score 0):

**Preface:**

Advanced customization of the package generated is possible by overriding resources used by jpackage, such as background images and template files for properties and scripts. The `--resource-dir` option is used to provide the overrides to the tool.

If the default resources that jpackage uses when packaging an application don't meet your needs, create a directory and add your customized files to it. If you override a file, your custom file must contain all of the properties that the default contains. Pass the path to the directory to jpackage using the `--resource-dir` option. The path can be absolute or relative to the current directory.

(https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/jpackage/override-jpackage-resources.html)

**Explanation about "--resource-dir":**

Path to override jpackage resources.
It can be an absolute path or relative to the current directory.

Icons, template files, and other resources of jpackage can be overridden by adding replacement resources to this directory.

(https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html)

**Additional information 1:**

If you use an external resources dir, then face the problem, that your project wants the resources dir "A" when in development, and the resources dir "B", when packaged.

You may want to create and use a custom made "switch" for pointing to the correct resources dir during development and when your project is packaged.

Or you may rewrite your code to look for resources in your JAR and if it is not available there, look into a specified dir relative to your JAR.

**Additional information 2:**

I know this is not what you are looking for, but again:

I recommend you to package the resources inside the JAR and if this is not possible for any reason, then package them inside the JAR **nevertheless, but extract them on application startup to "userhome/.appname" or somewhere else. Rewrite your code that you application extracts the files first and then uses them from the extracted location. You can extract them to a relative path from your JAR.**.

Then you will never run into all this troubles.

Comment: 1) Your suggestion to package the files into JAR, extract then reload it is good, it's just a question of "is it the only way of packaging resources?" If there are big resource files then they'll bulk up the JAR file. On slow computers, loading that bulky JAR into memory may degrade performance, or what I think is, the resource should be loaded in memory only when required.
2) If I use `--resource-dir` then how the path to the resource folder be specified in the program? The docs didn't mention any special way to access files from that folder.

Comment: To 1) Only classes are loaded into memory and stay there. Resources don't. If you use e.g. getClass().getResourceAsStream(), everytime a new stream from disk is created. They might be in memory because of hard drive caching or something like that. I would ZIP all needed files into a single ZIP, and extract that ZIP on startup.

Comment: To 2) First, please take a look again at "Additional information 1". Package all your resources with jpackage, check where it puts them relative to your JAR and get them within your JAR with a relative path. This will work when packaged, but NOT in development. You could create a "ResourceLoader" class, which loads the resources from classpath if they exist, and if not, it loads the resources from the relative path when packaged. Then exclude the resources from classpath when packaging your project, but don't exclude them from your VCS.

Comment: To 2), Do you have any suggestions on how to get the path of installation directory? I can only think of `new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath())` then `getParentFile().getParent()` to get to one level above the JAR file, assuming the resources folder is present one level above the JAR.

Comment: So I just tested the above code and it's working both in development and packaged without any extra switch on Linux. I'll put the answer after checking it on Windows system as well. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Great. :) Yes, the protectiondomain-way is the way to go here.